# Name of movie in which a New York woman finds herself

Tags: identify-this-movie

Identify this movie.  My memory may not be 100% accurate in all details.

Plot:  A woman, either divorced or separated from a long time boyfriend, learns to be on her own.

Category:  Feature for theatrical release

Language:  English

Production date:  About 1990s.

Setting:  About 1990s, New York City

Heroine:  Female, white, early 30s, American, urban professional, attractive

Lead actress:  In terms of recognition, a major actress who fell short of superstardom.

Technical:  Color

Length of title:  One or two words.  (It's a snappy title like *Lights Out* or *Uptick*.  I don't mean in terms of meaning, but the way it sounds.)

Memorable scenes:

- Heroine calls a masseur, who pays a home visit and ends up giving more than a massage (maybe not by accident).
- Heroine attends a party or goes to a club, takes ecstasy or some other party drug and falls into a choreographed dance routine with other women.  (The scene is not realistic and so you have to take it as an expression of her state of mind.)

(I am sorry that my first question is an "identify" question.  I saw some of the related posts and the concerns about this type of question.)

Comment: Good question, posted a possible match. And no need to apologize for ID questions just yet, especially when they're nicely detailed and structured like yours. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like [Living Out Loud](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120722/combined) from 1998 with Holly Hunter, Danny DeVito and other known faces.

> Judith Nelson quit her medical studies to marry. Years later, her husband, a physician, divorces her to be with another doctor. Deeply frustrated, she now lives alone in her luxury apartment in New York, looking for a new meaning for her life. Pat Francato, the janitor and lift-boy, has a troubled life himself: Gambling debts and the tragic death of his daughter took away all his spirit. One day, he and Judith meet in the right mood and a fragile friendship starts to grow.

Both of the scenes you mentioned are there and you can see glimpses of both of them in the trailer (the choreographed dance is around 1:30 and the massage is around 2:06):

Comment: from left to right the second female looks like oprah. lol 98 huh? hmm